# Django related objects and null foreign key

Tags: python, django, model

I want to make promotions system on my web page.

And I want few options:

- Give client discount for all products
- Give client discount for one of products
- Give all clients discount for one of products

How to make model to implement that?
I thought about using nullable foreign key in Promotion model, but how can I use related objects then in Product model, because I nedd all promotions with foreign key equal to client foreign key and all with foreign key = NULL?

Or maybe add some manager to product model, where I would search for promotional prices, depending on client's id?

Comment: Please read through the django basic tutorial, it did pretty well in model design and I'm sure you will learn more from there instead of here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design with the nullable fields is quite fine. You'll only need some thin wrappers around it.

Suppose you want to select all the promotions for the current user. That is, the promos that have the user selected, or that with no user specified. That's pretty easy achievable with Django:

```
from django.db.models import Q

class PromotionQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def for_user(self, user):
        return self.filter(Q(user=user) | Q(user__isnull=True))


class Promotion(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)

    objects = PromotionQuerySet.as_manager()


# and later in your code, say, in the view:
active_promos = Promotion.objects.for_user(request.user)
```

The same is true about the `Product` field.